# AutoNumber in Spatiallite

Tags: spatialite

I have a spatiallite database. In this database I have some attributes. One of them is the attribute `Nr_`. In this attribute the value must be assigned automatically and is not allowed to be a double. I would like it to be named as 1001,1002,1003 etc.

Comment: Try autoincrement on that attribute when creating the table.

Comment: Autoincrement seems to be supported only for primary key and not recommended even for that http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html. Probably you must write your own trigger.